# How is Java accepting my self signed certificate without me having to add it to Java truststore

Tags: java, ssl, amazon-ec2, apache-commons-net, ftps

I have set up an FTPS server on my aws ec2 instance and configured SSL using vsftpd. I created SSL certificate using -

```
sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
```

I used Apache Commons net to connect to my FTPS server and retrieve files using -

```
ftps = new FTPSClient(ftpsProtocol, isImplicit);

    try
    {
        int reply;

        ftps.connect(server);
        System.out.println("Connected to " + server + ".");

        // After connection attempt, you should check the reply code to verify
        // success.
        reply = ftps.getReplyCode();

        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
        {
            ftps.disconnect();
            System.err.println("FTP server refused connection.");
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        if (ftps.isConnected())
        {
            try
            {
                ftps.disconnect();
            }
            catch (IOException f)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR!");
                // do nothing
            }
        }
        System.err.println("Could not connect to server.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    __main:
    try
    {
        ftps.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftps.setBufferSize(1000);
        ftps.execPROT("P");

        if (!ftps.login(username, password))
        {
            ftps.logout();
            error = true;
            break __main;
        }
    }
```

This worked fine and I was able to retrieve files. Since it is not a CA certificate, how did Java accept the server's self signed certificate without throwing an error?

(My vsftpd conf has the following lines - 
    My vsftpd.conf has the following lines-

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO

local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=NO
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
require_ssl_reuse=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_max_port=12100
pasv_min_port=12000
port_enable=YES
```

)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not showing how you've initialised your `FTPSClient`, but I'll assume you've used the default values.

Looking at the [latest implementation of `FTPSClient` in the trunk of the Subversion repository](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/net/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPSClient.java?view=markup&pathrev=1697433), it's visibly using a `TrustManager` implementation coming from `TrustManagerUtils.getValidateServerCertificateTrustManager()` by default.

In turn, the [latest implementation of `TrustManagerUtils`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/net/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/net/util/TrustManagerUtils.java?view=markup&pathrev=1697433) reveals that this provides a `TrustManager` that only calls `checkValidity` on this certificate (and that's the option with validation turned on, not even the `ACCEPT_ALL` implementation). Unfortunately, `checkValidity` only checks that the certificate is valid at the current time, with respect to its "not before" and "not after" validity dates. It's not a verification of the certificate against any known trust anchor. This is essentially very close to useless, since attackers in a position to insert an incorrect certificate should be able to create one with the validity dates they want.

However, it seems that you can instantiate `FTPSClient` with an `SSLContext`, so using `new FTPSClient(SSLContext.getDefault())` would give you the default, more sensible behaviour (unless you've changed the default `SSLContext`). (Of course, you can also use a custom `SSLContext` with the correct behaviour, but initialised with a specific truststore too.)

I haven't checked the rest of the implementation, but I would have a look at what it does with hostname verifiers too, just in case.

(It's probably worth reporting this on the Apache Commons Net project. This default behaviour probably sounded like a good idea at the time, but it really isn't.)